# Tweepy output truncated

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, twitter

I am streaming with Tweepy 2.5 and everything seems fine, but the output is somehow truncated by `\u2026`, example:

```
+1487856347.451801::RT @scottbix: Fact: Trans people have way more to fear from cis people in bathrooms than cis people have to fear from trans people in bathr\u2026.
```

Comment: I checked the unicode that you put in, it appears that it is putting a ["horizontal ellipsis"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) wherever it says `\u2026`.

Comment: Thanks fin444, any suggestions how to fix it pls

Comment: My guess is that they cut the tweet off using the `...` to signify that they cut it off. But I can't be sure unless you provide an image of the exact source to see if that's the case.